# HTTP Error 404 (Not Found) if the CGI script starts with #!/usr/bin/env perl

Tags: perl

I have a CGI script whose content is not important. It works fine when executed from the web, but only if the first line is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

If I change it to

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

...then I got HTTP Error 404 (Not found).

When executed from the console, the script works properly in both cases. What is wrong?

---

### EDIT

I solved my problem with adding the following lines at the beginning of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use lib '/usr/local/lib64/perl5';
use lib '/usr/local/share/perl5';
use lib '/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl';
use lib '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl';
use lib '/usr/share/perl5';
use lib '/root/perl5/lib/perl5';
```

Obviously there is some problem with path, which I don't understand why, because when I execute script from the console, it works even without the use of `use lib`.

Comment: You want to ensure your script uses the `perl` with which your script was tested, so using `env` is a step in the wrong direction!

Comment: Your solution is bogus. You just added all of the core library locations for `/usr/bin/perl` and the local::lib for root (which hopefully isn't even readable to your CGI script). Set the shebang to the perl you want to use.

Comment: That "solution" is not ok at all. You will have major problems.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the problems have anything to do with each other, or the solution actually solves anything. If Apache can't find the script, it will still not be able to find it by adding the library paths. On the other hand, if there's any problem running the script the server would return a 500 status, not a 404. In every case, it's always the best to check the logs for the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your CGI environment probably has no `PATH`, or doesn't have `/usr/bin/` in `PATH`, therefore `env` doesn't find perl.